# in Django: How to get and display in template verbose_name of a model that their value is true, while name of field unknown?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model than has a lot of models.BooleanField declarations.

```
class a_lot_of_booleans(model.Models):
    old_or_new = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="is it an old or a new item")
    product_for_teens = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="is this product for teens")
    in_original_package = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="is this product in original package?")
```

Which then is used in some other classes like:

```
class product_for_sale(a_lot_of_booleans):
    U_Id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class product_for_buying(a_lot_of_booleans):
    U_Id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The class a_lot_of_booleans might change over time. Some booleans might get added some might get removed. What I need is to display a list of several entries, of the verbose_name, of only the true fields on one of the classes that inherit the a_lot_of_booleans class and the value of product_name, belonging to specific user.
What I"m trying in the views.py is the following:

```
def view_rfps(request):
    list=product_for_sale.objects.all().filter(U_Id=request.user)
    for item in list:
        values=item._meta.fields
        for value in values:
            res=item.objects.filter(**{value:'True'}) ##<< lines that fail
            print(res)
```

the above code fails on res=item.objects.filter(**{value:'True'}) on "Manager isn't accessible via search_for_constructor_rfp instances"
The idea later to pass on the res variable to view, however I cannot pass this point.
I have several items in list and for every list several boolean fields, that I"m not sure what they names gonna be in a future, so I cannot just use product_for_sale. in template later.
Any suggestion how to display the verbose name of unknown boolean field name ?

*edit*
Found a way:

```
    def view_rfps(request):
    list=product_for_sale.objects.all().filter(U_Id=request.user)
    for item in list:
        values=item._meta.fields
        for value in values:
            temp=getattr(item,value.name)
            if temp:
                print(value.verbose_name)
```

But if someone knows more efficient way, I"d love to hear

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
def view_rfps(request):
list=product_for_sale.objects.all().filter(U_Id=request.user)
for item in list:
    values=item._meta.fields
    for value in values:
        temp=getattr(item,value.name)
        if temp:
            print(value.verbose_name)
```